# Calling function would update the array?

Tags: java, arrays

If I would send an array to some function, for example :

```
public void arrayManipulate(Someclass [] arr){
arr[0] = 2
}
```

for example (lets say it array of ints, even though I wrote someclass)

```
Someclass [] arr = new Someclass[15]
this.arrayManipulate(arr);
System.out.print(arr[0]);
```

what will it print? 0 as the deadult value in the array, or 2 (I want to know if calling that function would update the array or that should i return the array in that function and do arr = this.arrayManipulate(arr))

thanks in advance
George

Answer (score 0):

If your code were to compile, and in both places the array were declared as int[], then the answer would be:

Yes, it will update the array. Although the `arr` object wouldn't have changed if reassigned in the `arrayManipulate` method, modifying an attribute/element inside it would be visible to the caller, because the updated object is the same.

So the number that would be printed is `2`